# How do I stop my function from returning 0?

Tags: c++, string, capitalization

I know the function has to return an integer, but in it, I print letter by letter in capital, and it also prints out the 0 that I am forced to return. I tried referencing `void capital(string& _name)` but this just gave me tons of errors. I think I need to return something inside the `for`, but I have no more ideas. What can I do?

```
int capital(string& _name){

    locale loc;

    for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i < _name.length(); i++){
        cout << std::toupper(_name[i], loc);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(){

    string name = "robbie";
    cout << capital(name) << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what error do you get when you make its return `void`?

Comment: Please get rid of [system("pause")](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html). It is gratuitously non-portable and dangerous. (What if I tried this program on my machine, and on my machine, the `pause` command pauses the cooling system on my home's nuclear reactor?)

Comment: @chris it was accusing me of using the wrong operator, cause I was using void instead of returning an int.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, yes. Many apologies.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Agreed ! But why would you _knowingly_ issue a `pause` on this system  in the first place :D ?

Comment: @P0W, well I copied and pasted for time restrictions, I must've forgot.

Comment: @P0W In this case, anyone even casually looking at the code can see the `system("pause");` and know it won't work on a system where `pause` doesn't do what you expect. The problem arises if someone doesn't look at the code, if it's in the middle of a lot of code, or if the behavior is somewhat obscured because the code isn't all in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
    cout << capital(name) << endl;
```

to this:

```
    capital(name);
    cout << endl;
```

Comment: this worked. thanks, but now it also works how I originally printed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make it return a string instead. Note that I don't output the string inside `capital`, just construct a new capitalized one and return it, but otherwise the logic is very similar to the original version.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string capital(const std::string& _name){

    std::locale loc;
    std::string name_copy = _name;

    for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i < name_copy.length(); i++){
        name_copy[i] = std::toupper(name_copy[i], loc);
    }

    return name_copy;
}

int main(){

    std::string name = "robbie";
    std::cout << capital(name) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This totally worked, I don't know how I didn't think of returning a string.

Comment: now, i get an error saying "not all control paths return a value" did I do something wrong? it just returns the first letter capitalized.

Comment: I'm unable to get the error you mention. I've updated the code so that it will compile as is.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely change the function's return type to void. Your issue is how you're calling the function in the main method.

Your `capital()` method is already doing the `cout`, so in your `main()`, change:

```
 cout << capital(name) << endl;
```

to:

```
capital(name) << endl;
```